# Cucumber Protractor tests is returning 0 scenarios

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, cucumber

I was trying to run a sample test in cucumber protractor javascript tests. But it is returning 0 scenarios.Could someone please look into my code pasted below.

**sample_scenario.feature**

`Feature:  To test version`

`@test`
`Scenario: To test the UI version of OFP`

`Given a verification order is created`
`| orderOrigin    | OFX4    |
      | orderType      | VOE     |
      | isNewEmployer  | true    |
      | verifierClient | default |`

`Given OFP is used by "ldap" user
    And the version is verified`

**ofp_order_processing_steps.js**

`let ofpHomePage = require('../../pages/ofp_pages/task_pages/ofp_home_page');`

`Given(/^the version is verified$/, { timeout: 720 * 1000 }, function () {
  return ofpHomePage.verifyVersion(this.verificationOrder.preProcessingData.employee);
});`

**ofp_home_page.js**

`let OfpTaskBasePage = require('./ofp_task_base_page');`

`class ofpHomePage extends OfpTaskBasePage {`

`constructor() {`

```
super();
this.uiVersion = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/sd-home/efx-footer/footer/div/div[3]/p[1]'));
```

}

`verifyVersion(employee) {
    return browser.wait(this.isVisible(this.uiVersion))`
   `.then(() => {`
        `expect(this.uiVersion.getText()).to.eventually.equal(employee.uiVersion);
      });
  }`

}
`module.exports = new ofpHomePage();`

Answer (score 1):

Your given step doesn't match the one defined in your scenario, this makes your scenario invalid which means the output is correct , there are 0 valid scenarios.

```
You specify - Given a verification order is created

You provide - Given(/^the version is verified$/)
```

if you want it to match then you need provide a matching given step.

```
Given(^a verification order is created$/)
```

Additionally you might want to look into parameterising for more flexibility and storing the verification info and result for other steps to use.